# linter pylint is not installed vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know there are multiple version of this question on SO, I've tried the solutions posted on those threads and they don't seem to help :(

I have VS Code installed in an Ubuntu VM. I can't seem to get the python linter to work. i.e. I get a message saying

```
Linter pylint is not installed
```

I am pretty sure pylint is installed on the VM because when I run `which pylint` I have a valied output.

Here are the outputs for `which python` and `which pylint` respectively

```
/usr/bin/python
/home/rakshak/.local/bin/pylint
```

And I have the following in my User settings and workspace settings in VS Code

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
       "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
       "python.linting.pylintPath": "/home/rakshak/.local/bin/pylint",
       "python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, turns out this was just a permissions issue!

When I got the `pylint not installed` message, I was presented with a button to "Install pylint" this runs

> sudo pip install pylint

This changed the owner of my `.local/lib/` to root and made it inaccessible to vscode.

Output of `ls -ld ~/.local/lib/` was

> drwx------ 3 root root 4096 Sep 24 10:49 /home/*userName*/.local/lib/

Runing chown with my group and user fixed this issue.

> sudo chown -R *group:user* ~/.local

now the output of `ls -ld ~/.local/lib/` reads

> drwx------ 3 *userGroup* *userName* 4096 Sep 24 10:49
>   /home/rakshak/.local/lib/

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked with which python version you have installed pylint?
If you have used python 3.6 then the setting has to be like this:

`"python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3.6"`

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying! Turns out this was just a permissions issue. I am going to document my solution here for anyone else who faces this problem.